# Built in way to apply a function to successive members of a list and return a new list

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-2.7

I'm looking for a built in function in python that applies a function to each element and the next element within a list (or other iterable), returning the set of results in a new list. I don't know if one is built in or not, but I'm attempting to approach this in a functional way if possible.

Example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
# returns [3,5,7,9]
# add(1,2) add(2,3) add(3,4) add(4,5)
```

My actual use case is that I have a list of vectors of the form `numpy.array([1,2,3])`, and I want to find the difference between each successive vector.

Actual example:

```
l = [numpy.array([1,2,3]), numpy.array([2,7,6]), numpy.array([4,5,6])]
# find the difference between each vector (l[0]-l[1], l[1]-[l2], .. etc)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want [`pairwise()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) and `map()`.

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward way to do this would be in a list comprehension:

```
a = [l[i] + l[i+1] for i in range(len(l)-1)]
```

Alternatively, you could use a little builtin magic:

```
map(sum, zip(l, l[1:]))
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Please comment on what was unsatisfactory and/or wrong about this answer.

Comment: +1 to vote against the downvote! I find this a perfectly acceptable solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I imagine the map/sum/zip approach might be expensive in memory.

Comment: @Daenyth: Yes, I see what you mean. I merely wanted to illustrate the performance of an implied loop using `map()` as versus a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the differences between successive entries of a NumPy array can be done with `numpy.diff()`:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([5, 2, 3, 1, 4])
>>> numpy.diff(a)
array([-3,  1, -2,  3])
```

This will be much faster than any pure-Python solution.

**Edit**: Here's an example for a 2d array:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3], [2,7,6], [4,5,6]])
>>> numpy.diff(a, axis=0)
array([[ 1,  5,  3],
       [ 2, -2,  0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Updated my question - it's a list of numpy.arrays that I need to find the difference between.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: Using a list of NumPy arrays somehow defies the whole point of NumPy.  Use a two-dimensional NumPy array instead, and then use `numpy.diff()`.

Comment: This is the first time I've used NumPy, would you mind elaborating on diffing a two-d numpy array?

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: I added an example.

Comment: Just to let you know, I went with this solution as it fits my problem more specifically - but accepted the more general answer. Thanks for your help.